# Subquery error message

Tags: sql-server

I'm encountering the below error message when I execute the query. It was suggested by a member that I check the alias on my subqueries. I did and they seem in line.

Can you guys provide some insight? Thank you.

**An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.**

```
Select CLINIC_ID,SUMMARY_CATGRY,ENTRY_TYPE,
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 1 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Jan12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 2 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Feb12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 3 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Mar12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 4 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Apr12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 5 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [May12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 6 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Jun12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 7 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Jul12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 8 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Aug12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 9 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Sep12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 10 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end)[Oct12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 11 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end)[Nov12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 12 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end)[Dec12],
SUM(case when EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [2012YTD],
SUM(case when EntryYear = 2011 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [2011YTD]
From
(
    SELECT [Non_Recurring_Clinic_Step1].CLINIC_ID, 
        dbo_HR_FINAN_CLASS.SUMMARY_CATGRY, 
        [TABLE_LAYOUT].ENTRY_TYPE, 
        datepart(month,[entry_date]) EntryMonth,
        datepart(year,[entry_date]) EntryYear,
        [sumofentry_amount]

 FROM [TABLE_LAYOUT]
 Inner Join

(
SELECT [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].CLINIC_ID, OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.CHARGE_CLASS,[GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].PATIENT_NUMBER, [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].REGISTRATION_CD, OUTPAT_REGISTER.PRIMARY_FINAN,   Replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.ENTRY_DATE,101), '/', '') AS ENTRY_DATE, SUM(ENTRY_AMOUNT) AS ENTRY_AMOUNT 

FROM
OUTPAT_REGISTER
Left JOIN
OUTPAT_BILL_REF
ON(OUTPAT_REGISTER.PATIENT_NUMBER = OUTPAT_BILL_REF.PATIENT_NUMBER)
AND(OUTPAT_REGISTER.REGISTRATION_CD = OUTPAT_BILL_REF.REGISTRATION_CD)

Left JOIN
OUTPAT_ACCT_REC
ON(OUTPAT_BILL_REF.PATIENT_NUMBER = OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.PATIENT_NUMBER)
AND(OUTPAT_BILL_REF.BILL_REFERENCE = OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.REFERENCE_NUM)

Left JOIN
    (
SELECT CLINIC_ID, PATIENT_NUMBER, REGISTRATION_CD
FROM OP_VISIT_HISTRY
GROUP BY CLINIC_ID, PATIENT_NUMBER, REGISTRATION_CD
--ORDER BY CLINIC_ID
)AS [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID]

ON(OUTPAT_REGISTER.PATIENT_NUMBER = [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].PATIENT_NUMBER)
AND(OUTPAT_REGISTER.REGISTRATION_CD =[GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].REGISTRATION_CD)

GROUP BY [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].CLINIC_ID,OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.CHARGE_CLASS,[GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].PATIENT_NUMBER,[GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].REGISTRATION_CD,
OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.ENTRY_DATE,OUTPAT_REGISTER.PRIMARY_FINAN

HAVING OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.ENTRY_DATE >'12/31/2010'
)AS [Non_Recurring_Clinic_Step1]

On([TABLE_LAYOUT].ENTRY_CLASS = [Non_Recurring_Clinic_Step1].CHARGE_CLASS)

Inner Join
OUTPAT_REGISTER

On([Non_Recurring_Clinic_Step1].PATIENT_NUMBER = OUTPAT_REGISTER.PATIENT_NUMBER)
And([Non_Recurring_Clinic_Step1].REGISTRATION_CD = OUTPAT_REGISTER.REGISTRATION_CD)

Inner Join
OUTPAT_AREA_CDS
On(OUTPAT_REGISTER.REGISTER_AREA = OUTPAT_AREA_CDS.REGISTER_AREA)

Inner Join
HR_FINAN_CLASS.FINAN_CLASS_CD
On(OUTPAT_REGISTER.PRIMARY_FINAN = HR_FINAN_CLASS.FINAN_CLASS_CD)

Where dbo_OUTPAT_AREA_CDS.REG_AREA_TYPE)<>'RE'
        and datepart(year,[entry_date]) in (2011, 2012)
) src
group by CLINIC_ID, SUMMARY_CATGRY, ENTRY_TYPE
```

Comment: Might I suggest that you start by removing `SUM`s from the query.  If that doesn't help, at least you've eliminated a heap of stuff that you've given the rest of us to wade through.  Then work through eliminating a `JOIN` at a time until the problem vanishes.  As you try to pare the code down to the smallest example that demonstrates the problem you might stumble across the answer yourself!  It's almost like debugging.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I've only been using SQL for a couple of months now, and your suggestion is and will be useful going forward as I start to encounter more issues when developing other queries.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you have an extra parentheses on this line:

```
Where dbo_OUTPAT_AREA_CDS.REG_AREA_TYPE)<>'RE'  -- there is a closing but no opening
                                       ^ -- this is extra
```

I found this by formatting the code to find the matching parentheses.

So your full query will be:

```
Select CLINIC_ID,
    SUMMARY_CATGRY,
    ENTRY_TYPE,
    SUM(case when EntryMonth = 1 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Jan12],
    SUM(case when EntryMonth = 2 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Feb12],
    SUM(case when EntryMonth = 3 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Mar12],
    SUM(case when EntryMonth = 4 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Apr12],
    SUM(case when EntryMonth = 5 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [May12],
    SUM(case when EntryMonth = 6 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Jun12],
    SUM(case when EntryMonth = 7 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Jul12],
    SUM(case when EntryMonth = 8 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Aug12],
    SUM(case when EntryMonth = 9 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Sep12],
    SUM(case when EntryMonth = 10 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end)[Oct12],
    SUM(case when EntryMonth = 11 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end)[Nov12],
    SUM(case when EntryMonth = 12 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end)[Dec12],
    SUM(case when EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [2012YTD],
    SUM(case when EntryYear = 2011 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [2011YTD]
From
(
    SELECT [Non_Recurring_Clinic_Step1].CLINIC_ID, 
        dbo_HR_FINAN_CLASS.SUMMARY_CATGRY, 
        [TABLE_LAYOUT].ENTRY_TYPE, 
        datepart(month,[entry_date]) EntryMonth,
        datepart(year,[entry_date]) EntryYear,
        ENTRY_AMOUNT as [sumofentry_amount]
    FROM [TABLE_LAYOUT]
    Inner Join
    (
        SELECT [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].CLINIC_ID, 
            OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.CHARGE_CLASS,
            [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].PATIENT_NUMBER, 
            [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].REGISTRATION_CD, 
            OUTPAT_REGISTER.PRIMARY_FINAN,   
            Replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.ENTRY_DATE,101), '/', '') AS ENTRY_DATE, 
            SUM(ENTRY_AMOUNT) AS ENTRY_AMOUNT 
        FROM OUTPAT_REGISTER
        Left JOIN OUTPAT_BILL_REF
            ON OUTPAT_REGISTER.PATIENT_NUMBER = OUTPAT_BILL_REF.PATIENT_NUMBER
            AND OUTPAT_REGISTER.REGISTRATION_CD = OUTPAT_BILL_REF.REGISTRATION_CD
        Left JOIN OUTPAT_ACCT_REC
            ON OUTPAT_BILL_REF.PATIENT_NUMBER = OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.PATIENT_NUMBER
            AND OUTPAT_BILL_REF.BILL_REFERENCE = OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.REFERENCE_NUM
        Left JOIN
        (
            SELECT CLINIC_ID, PATIENT_NUMBER, REGISTRATION_CD
            FROM OP_VISIT_HISTRY
            GROUP BY CLINIC_ID, PATIENT_NUMBER, REGISTRATION_CD
        )AS [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID]
            ON OUTPAT_REGISTER.PATIENT_NUMBER = [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].PATIENT_NUMBER
            AND OUTPAT_REGISTER.REGISTRATION_CD =[GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].REGISTRATION_CD
        WHERE OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.ENTRY_DATE >'12/31/2010'
        GROUP BY [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].CLINIC_ID,
            OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.CHARGE_CLASS,
            [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].PATIENT_NUMBER,
            [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].REGISTRATION_CD,
            OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.ENTRY_DATE,
            OUTPAT_REGISTER.PRIMARY_FINAN
    )AS [Non_Recurring_Clinic_Step1]
        On [TABLE_LAYOUT].ENTRY_CLASS = [Non_Recurring_Clinic_Step1].CHARGE_CLASS
    Inner Join OUTPAT_REGISTER
        On [Non_Recurring_Clinic_Step1].PATIENT_NUMBER = OUTPAT_REGISTER.PATIENT_NUMBER
        And [Non_Recurring_Clinic_Step1].REGISTRATION_CD = OUTPAT_REGISTER.REGISTRATION_CD
    Inner Join OUTPAT_AREA_CDS
        On OUTPAT_REGISTER.REGISTER_AREA = OUTPAT_AREA_CDS.REGISTER_AREA
    Inner Join HR_FINAN_CLASS.FINAN_CLASS_CD
        On OUTPAT_REGISTER.PRIMARY_FINAN = HR_FINAN_CLASS.FINAN_CLASS_CD
    Where dbo_OUTPAT_AREA_CDS.REG_AREA_TYPE<>'RE'
        and datepart(year,[entry_date]) in (2011, 2012)
) src
group by CLINIC_ID, SUMMARY_CATGRY, ENTRY_TYPE
```

Comment: Wow, you made it pretty and it's still ugly

Comment: @AaronBertrand yeah it is ugly

Comment: +1 for the beautification...

Comment: ok, deleted the extra parenthesis and got this error message: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
Invalid column name 'sumofentry_amount'. Yes, it sure ain't pretty, but I will work on making my formatting better. lol.

Comment: @user2026836 see my edit. You had the column called `entry_amount` in the subquery. I changed it to `ENTRY_AMOUNT as [sumofentry_amount]`

Comment: Bluefeet, the query executed for 1:37 with out error and then I got this: Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

Comment: @user2026836 I am not sure, I can only suggest that you start with the inner subqueries and work outward adding joins, etc to see what the issue is

Comment: Bluefeet- thanks. You have been quiet helpful so far. I really appreciate your insight.

Answer (score 4):

One issue I see is in the following section:

```
Where dbo_OUTPAT_AREA_CDS.REG_AREA_TYPE)<>'RE'
        and datepart(year,[entry_date]) in (2011, 2012)
) src
```

Looks like you have an extra, unmatched paren at `dbo_OUTPAT_AREA_CDS.REG_AREA_TYPE)<>'RE'`... instead, this should be:

```
Where dbo_OUTPAT_AREA_CDS.REG_AREA_TYPE<>'RE'
        and datepart(year,[entry_date]) in (2011, 2012)
) src
```

Comment: ok, deleted the extra parenthesis and got this error message: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
Invalid column name 'sumofentry_amount'.